# "Layout" folder not appearing in "res" folder

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Recently I installed android studio and wanted to create a map, selected java language instead of kotlin.

As I was following a guide on internet, 
https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/install-and-set-up.htm

it said to select "Main_activity.xml" in res->layout.
But I couldn't find any layout folder.

Here's the image of my project view:[Android Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBEY3.png)

Thank You

Comment: Have you created the main activity already? It has to show in the java folder. My guess is that you don't have any activity yet, therefore the layout folder was not auto-created yet. Simply create a new activity or manually create the layout folder in res and then add the desired layout xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your "Android Project View"
In Java folder, you can see  three "com.ecample.hackathon" folders, among these three folders first one is blank, when we create any Activity in our project, java class show at here, and xml file show in layout folder(parent is res folder).

So now, you have to create Activity.

Steps:

1) Right click on this empty folder "com.ecample.hackathon"

2) Select New

3) Than  Select Activity

4) As per your choice you can select the option.
   Ex. Select "Empty Activity

Name as according your use.
You can get java and xml file in proper place. 
Hope this help you.